# Programmatically verify whether TTL enabled on Cosmos DB collections

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Is it currently possible programmatically using cosmos sql api & c# to verify whether TTL enabled on certain collection, if not then enable it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the following code should help.

```
CosmosClient client = new CosmosClient(connection, options );              

Container container = await GetContainer(client, "database1", "container1");
ContainerProperties containerProperties = await container.ReadContainerAsync();

int? ttl = containerProperties.DefaultTimeToLive;
```